# Requiring help to understand arrays

Tags: c, arrays, cs50

I'm learning about arrays in C and I can't figure out why the following is not correct?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    string plaintext = get_string();

    int x = 5;
    long long N = strlen(plaintext);
    string a = plaintext;
    long long c = 0;
    int z = x;

    for(int i = 0; i < N + (N/x) ; i++)
    {

        if( i == x)
        {
            a[c] = 32;
            c++;
            z = (z + x);
            //printf("%c\n", a[c]);           
        }

        a[c] = plaintext[i];
        //printf("%c\n", a[c]); 
        c++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

It's meant to insert spaces into a string of text after every x chars... I know it's not efficient (I reckon I need something called pointers) but why isn't it working? I went through it using a debugger and it seems like my original string is changing as I go... but why?

Comment: Please find a better title first.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `string` is not a thing in C

Comment: Are you sure it's c or c++? There is no `string` datatype in c

Comment: It's probably the `string` from the ever so popular `"cs50.h"`, which is just a typedef to `char *`.

Comment: it must be in a library I'm including,  i promise other 'string' arrays work... Do you recon it's a consequence of the they've implemented the function?

Comment: @ M Ohem, yes exactly

Comment: There is no array **shown** in your code. It is not clear what your problem is. Follow the comments and provide a [mcve]! Typedefing a pointer is very bad practice and does no good at all. And `char *` is **not and array**, but a pointer. They are not identical types.

Comment: The problem with using `string` is that it isn't standard C and many people don't know what it is. If you use `char` it is clear that you use the C notation of string, namely a null-terminated array of `char` and those trying to help you will immediately know what you mean.

Comment: _"I've been coding for less than a week"_ Okay so study for another week. Then another. Don't just give up.

Comment: The return value of `strlen()` has type `size_t`, not `long long`. In general, use `size_t` when you are talking about lengths of buffers and (unsigned) offsets into buffers.

Comment: If "cs50.h" hides `char*` behind a `typedef char* string` you need to stop using that library. And possibly introduce whoever wrote it to a baseball bat, for wasting your time and teaching you bad practice.

Comment: @Lundin: The problem is that whoever wrote it is a teacher and acquainting them to the business end of a baseball bat will stop your CS career for orther reasons. `:(`

Comment: haha thank you very much. This is an amazing community, I'm very grateful.

Comment: @MOehm It is a good cause though. Incompetent programming teachers is one of the biggest problems in the whole SW industry. I suppose working as an actual programmer pays better than teaching. It is a sad state of affairs: programming should be taught to student by the best programmers, not by the worst.

Comment: @Lundin: Oh, I'm not questioning your motives here.

Comment: @Lundin, I think that's a bit extreme. `cs50` is a well reputed Harvard course and they sure know what they are doing to help students learn fundamentals of programming.

Comment: @RoadRunner No, sorry, a person who writes `typedef char* string` doesn't know what they are doing. Even if you could somehow justify hiding a pointer behind a typedef, you aren't going to be able to justify using the same type name as C++ std::string. It will create confusion, bugs and namespace conflicts.

Comment: @RoadRunner: That such courses are "well reputed" is just another facet of the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `string` is `char *` then `text` and `a` point to the same string. That explains why your original string changes. What you can do is:

```
string a= malloc(N+1 + N/x +1);
```

This allocates space for a new string, into which you copy the original with a space after every `x` characters. Add 1 for the terminating null character and 1 "to be safe" when `x` or `N` are odd.

Comment: That's done it, thank you so much. of course then new array needs more memory, i just assumed that it would extend to fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define freinput "input.txt","r",stdin
#define freoutput "output.txt","w",stdout
#define mp make_pair
#define fi first
#define sc second
#define ellapse printf("Time : %0.3lf\n",clock()*1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long int uld;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<string> vs;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
string s;
string stringInsertion(int x,string neww){

    for(int i = 0;i<s.size();i++){
        if(i!=0 && i%x==0){
            neww=neww+' '+s[i];
        }
        else neww+=s[i];
    }
    return neww;
}
int main(){

    cin>>s;
    int x = 2;
    string neww="";
    cout<<stringInsertion(x,neww);
}
```

just set the x number.hope this help

Comment: Isn't this C++? the question is in C.

Comment: well,you can just replace the string variable into char.I'm just helping with the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's do something similar first: Print out the string with spaces. Use `i` to loop through the string. Every time `i` is evenly divisibly by `x`, we print a space before we print the character, but not at the beginning:

```
void print_spaced(const char *s, int x)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (i && i % x == 0) putchar(' ');
        putchar(s[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

You don't need to determine the length beforehand, because you can stop when you hit the terminating null character. That is, keep going as long as `s[i]` is not null. (Recall that `s[i]` is the same as `s[i] != '\0'` and similarly, `i` is the same as `i != 0`.)

Now let's fill a char array with the spaced out string instead of printing it:

```
int space_out_unsafe(char *res, const char *s, int x)
{
    int i, k = 0;

    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (i && i % x == 0) res[k++] = ' ';
        res[k++] = s[i];
    }

    res[k] = '\0';
    return k;
}
```

This function takes an additional parameter: A char buffer to fill. It has a second index, `k`, which is the current length of the result buffer. Whenever we printed in the first version, we now append a character to the string:

```
res[k++] = '#';
```

Tis overwrites the current end and moves `k` on one position. We don't write a newline at the end, but we must null-terminate the result.

There is one problem, though: The buffer may overflow; note how I have labelled the function above `unsafe`. Arrays in C have a fixed size and won't grow automatically when something is appended. It is there fore a good idea to pass the maximum buffer size `max` to the function and check for overflow before appending:

```
int space_out(char *res, int max, const char *s, int x)
{
    int i, k = 0;

    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (i && i % x == 0 && k < max - 1) res[k++] = ' ';
        if (k < max - 1) res[k++] = s[i];
    }

    res[k] = '\0';
    return k;
}
```

You can now use this function like this:

```
char res[20];

space_out(res, sizeof(res), "Doremifasola", 2);
puts(res);
```

There are other ways to accomplish this. You could allocate the memory dynamically, as Paul suggested. That way, you can cater for the additional space you need, but you also make the caller of the function take care of cleaning up the allocated memory with `free`. Dynamically allocating memory is something to look into after your first week. `:)`

Another possibility is to space out the string in place, that modify the contents of the original buffer. You still have to take care to provide the extra space, though. (Usually, in-place midofication is used when the result string is shorter, e.g. when filtering out characters.) You should also process your string from the and as not to overwrite data you need later with spaces. If you feel confident, that's an exercise for next week, too.